# Identify a replacement 12-pin ribbon cable push in socket

Tags: identification, connector, components, repair, replacement

I need to identify a replacement for this 12 pin flat cable connector. I don't seem to be able to find the right google terms to come up with a useful result. A 12 pin AWM 2896 cable plugs into this. It seems to be a 2 row package (pins are staggered in two rows), and if I understand `pitch` correctly, a ~1.26mm pitch.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an FFC socket, LIF (Low Insertion Force), straight, thru-hole, 1.25 mm pitch.

[image: Molex 52045]

{source:  Digikey}

Made by:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam Tech - PCB 1.25mm
- JST - FE
- Molex - 52044
- Molex - 52045
- TE - 84533
- TE - 84534

I found it using my [connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?sm=N&nm=N&bm=K&c=direct_to_board_comp&u=cable_sockets&o=ffc_fpc_sockets&f=ffc_fpc_lif_sockets&fl=000000000000-f-%7C%7C1.25)